Can I claim back US tax from the last 9 years as a result of not filling in W-8BEN forms?
I am a UK citizen. I have personally owned shares in a US company for the last 9 years.
I failed to fill in a W-8BEN form for the last 9 years.
I have lived in the UK and have done all my life.
How do I claim back this tax?

What tax are you claiming back? There's no tax on ownership of shares.

@littleadv If it pays dividends, those are taxed.

@Barmar but the OP didn't mention any dividends.

They didn't mention much of anything. But if there's tax to claim back, there must have been income.

Were US taxes withheld? Did you file US tax returns?
